# How can i find the duplicates in array of numbers + the counter how each number is repeated inside

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to find duplicates that are inside array more or equal to two times. If i have array of strings for example this would work

```
var arrStr = 'i do   as as     becasue               i do as';


function CheckDuplicates(sentence)
{
  let arr = sentence.split(" ");
  let counter = {};
  let duplicates = [];

  for(let i = 0;i < arr.length;i++)
  {
    let item = arr[i];
    counter[item] = counter[item] >= 1 ? counter[item] += 1 : 1;
    if(item != "")
    {
      if(counter[item] == 2)
      {
        duplicates.push(item);
      }
    }
  }

  Object.keys(counter)
  .filter(key => !duplicates.includes(key))
  .forEach(k => delete counter[k]);

  return {
    duplicates: duplicates,
    counter: counter
  };

}


let r = CheckDuplicates(arrStr);

c.log(r.duplicates);
c.log(r.counter);
```

as i result i get in the console

```
["as", "i", "do"]
{i: 2, do: 2, as: 3}
```

but with this same code if i try to do this with array of numbers i get {} in the `c.log(r.counter);`

i don't know why includes is not working with the numbers in this case

```
var arr = [9, 9,  9 ,111, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 7 , 7];

function CheckDuplicates(sentence)
{
  let counter = {};
  let duplicates = [];

  for(let i = 0;i < arr.length;i++)
  {
    let item = arr[i];
    counter[item] = counter[item] >= 1 ? counter[item] += 1 : 1;
    if(item != "")
    {
      if(counter[item] == 2)
      {
        duplicates.push(item);
      }
    }
  }

  Object.keys(counter)
  .filter(key => !duplicates.includes(key))
  .forEach(k => delete counter[k]);

  return {
    duplicates: duplicates,
    counter: counter
  };

}


let r = CheckDuplicates(arr);

c.log(r.duplicates);
c.log(r.counter);
```

so in the console i get

```
[9, 4, 7]
{}
```

Comment: i think the issue is that object keys returns your keys as strings, while includes check also type (triple equal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Object.keys` returns the keys as strings, and `includes` checks for type equality too.

The commented line is the only thing I changed and your code is working fine (I am casting to string when pushing into `duplicates` but you can also fix it while using `includes`)

```js
var arr = [9, 9,  9 ,111, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 7 , 7];

function CheckDuplicates(sentence)
{
  let counter = {};
  let duplicates = [];

  for(let i = 0;i < arr.length;i++)
  {
    let item = arr[i];
    counter[item] = counter[item] >= 1 ? counter[item] += 1 : 1;
    if(item != "")
    {
      if(counter[item] == 2)
      {
        duplicates.push(`${item}`); // casting to string
      }
    }
  }

  Object.keys(counter)
  .filter(key => !duplicates.includes(key))
  .forEach(k => delete counter[k]);

  return {
    duplicates: duplicates,
    counter: counter
  };

}


let r = CheckDuplicates(arr);

console.log(r.duplicates);
console.log(r.counter);
```